# Output from plugin to appear on specific pages with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am currently trying to do research on how to output a result from a WordPress custom plugin to the frontend of WordPress. I have trying adding filters, do actions, add actions. But nothing seems to work. I know the add_action works for child themes because I'm currently using a script to do so.

The script below works for the child theme but not in a plugins functions.php page.

```
    function displayPages()
    {
      $pageIDs = "List of page ids";

       if(is_page($pageIDs))
       {
         include_once 'script.js';
       }
    }
   add_action('wp_footer', 'displayPages')
```

Here is the current code I was trying use to fix the problem with the plugin.

```
    function getPageIDs()
    {
       include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/stage/wp-config.php' );
        global $wpdb;

       $row = $wpdb->get_row( 'SELECT pages FROM schemalocalbusiness WHERE id = 1');


        $pageIDs = $row->pages;

        $pageIDsArray = explode(",", $pageIDs);


        foreach($pageIDsArray as $perma)
        {
            echo ' ' . esc_url( get_permalink($perma) ) . '<br>';
        }

    }

function includeShemaOnPage()
{

    $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";


    if(getPageID() == $acturla_link)
    {
        print 'SUCCESS';
    }
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'includeShemaOnPage');
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: `(getPageID() == $acturla_link)` this will never be true for as long as this isnt true `$actual_link == $acturla_link`

Comment: Not sure I understand. Could you please elaborate a little? Thank you @miknik!

Comment: Your variable names in `includeShemaOnPage()` aren't spelled the same

Comment: In your includeSchemaOnPage function, you are calling the function getPageID() instead of getPageIDs().

Comment: Yeah, still not working. Thanks @Yamu